# AJAX-CodeIgniter POST not reaching my controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am about to bleed from this piece of code...have checked many posts and tut's online and my code is not that different but no matter how I tweaked it, it failed. Basically, i wanna send a post request to my controller. I don't have a form, just a select option with a button.

Issue:

1. When I click the button first, my console don't show anything. On second click, sometimes it doesnt show any value.
2. Definitely on third click on words, it displays 403: Forbidden

So, essentially the request never reaches my controller.

What am i doing wrong here?

HTML:

```
<select id="rec"><option value="1">1</option</select> <input type="button" id="process" value="Process"/>
```

Javascript:

```
$("#process").click(function() {
  if (!$("#rec option:selected").length) {

  return false;
}

  var postForm = { //Fetch form data
        'lang':$("#rec option:selected").val(), //Store name fields value
        '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name();?>': '<?php   echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash();?>'
    };

   $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo base_url()?>tasks/process",

            data: postForm,
            dataType : "json",
            cache: "false",
            success: function (result) {
                alert(result);
            }
        });


 });
```

My Controller is just:

```
 class Tasks extends CI_Controller {


 public function __construct()
    {
             parent::__construct();



    }

  function process(){
//process the posted item here



 }
 //------end class here
 }

?>
```

Comment: Is jQuery code wrapped in `$(document).ready(function(){`?

Comment: [Remove](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/styleguide.html#php-closing-tag) closing php tag from controller. And edit question with some code from method. This way you pass back nothing to AJAX.

Comment: @sam sam on codeIgniter controllers no need to use close php tags.

Comment: @Tpojka good spot! I must have added it in the post cos my controller don't have it.

Comment: @wolfgang1983 thanks too...

Comment: @charlietfl thanks a lot man! That solved the problem essentially. It is so weird cos i have a log in function that works like a charm and the interface is more or less the same. But doc.ready seems smooth enough as I tried it in others. . Wanna vote plus you but...not yet able to do so. Thanks man!

Comment: If you don't use it...the script needs to be included in page after elements it references exist

Comment: I see a lot of people saying it, it may not be required to use the closing tags on controllers but this will not be a cause of breaking code with ajax. What to do is check the console and network tab in your dev tool of the browser, that's where you most likely will find what's wrong with the code.